# Android - Saving data on external storage

Tags: android

I have an audio file named "s1" in my raw folder in my project, and I put the following code onto a button on the main screen, when I run my emulator and press run, it crashes the program. If anyone can provide any help or solutions I would be eternally grateful

```
public void fileSetup() {

    File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC);
    String name1 = "Zen1";
    File file1 = new File(path, name1 + ".mp3");
    path.mkdirs();
    InputStream is1 = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.s1); 
    try {
         OutputStream os1 = new FileOutputStream(file1);
         byte[] data1 = new byte [is1.available()]; 
         is1.read(data1);
         os1.write(data1);
         is1.close();
         os1.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
```

Logcat output:

```
01-24 23:00:42.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1064): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-24 23:00:42.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1064): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method saveData(View) in the activity class com.malthorn.zenstatemeditation.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'button1'
01-24 23:00:42.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1064):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3620)
01-24 23:00:42.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1064):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
01-24 23:00:42.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1064):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
01-24 23:00:42.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1064):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
01-24 23:00:42.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1064):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-24 23:00:42.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1064):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-24 23:00:42.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1064):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
01-24 23:00:42.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1064):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-24 23:00:42.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1064):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-24 23:00:42.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1064):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
01-24 23:00:42.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1064):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-24 23:00:42.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1064):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-24 23:00:42.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1064): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: saveData [class android.view.View]
01-24 23:00:42.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1064):     at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:423)
01-24 23:00:42.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1064):     at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:787)
01-24 23:00:42.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1064):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3613)
01-24 23:00:42.137: E/AndroidRuntime(1064):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: You're going to have to provide more than "it crashes the program" to get any real help. You'll have to provide the logcat output so we can see exactly what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't do anything if you don't provide the logcat with the exception!

A completely blind guess would be that you are missing the permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**Edit**

Solution based on what I've seen of the code

It seems like your MainActivity is being called from a click listener set via XML, with an action saveData.

I noted that on line 44 you have a method called savaData with no parameters. A click listener called from XML needs a view, so the fix is to change line 44 in your pastebin to this:

```
  public void saveData(View view) {
```

Make sure you note the <kbd>a</kbd> changed to an <kbd>e</kbd> on the word save!

Comment: added the logcat, sorry

Comment: OK that log cat seema to indicate you're calling save data somewhere, although I'd expect that to show up when compiling. The problem doesn't appear to be with your saving code, can you post the whole class (activity) that contains this

Comment: I cant believe such an obvious answer was in front of my face! Haha thank you so much! If I put this in an activity's OnCreate, will it still work? like in the oncreate i put "saveData();"

Comment: Yes, I think it should, but make sure you catch any exceptions otherwise it could result in an unstartable activity again (this is assuming you remove the android:onClick from the XML), also please mark my answer as accepted if its fixed your issue, thanks